# How to create spring batch admin application using STS tool

Tags: spring, user-interface, spring-batch, admin

How to create simple application for spring batch admin UI using STS or eclipse.

Comment: Spring Batch Admin is not maintained anymore. You can use Spring Cloud Data Flow as a replacement: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In STS

File => New => Spring Legacy Project

In the dialog that appears expand the Batch folder and then select Spring Batch Admin Webapp..